# Outlook 2010 Context Menu For Embedded Attachments - idMso?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I am working on Otlook 2010 add-in and currently customizing Ribbon UI. So far so good, but I have one problem with customizing context menu for embedded objects in mails. I have tried many **idMso** context menus, but none of them is working.

Do anyone have experience **which idMso is context menu shown below** or **how to add new button there**?

[image]

Sample of my custom-ribbon.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="OnRibbonLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuText">
      <button id="MyContextMenuText"
              imageMso="HappyFace"
              label="ContextMenuAttachments"
              onAction="OnMyButtonClick" />
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xml seems fine. But depending on what you click, there is a different context menu showing up.

The `ContextMenuText` is the context menu which shows up on right click 
when writing or editing email.

`ContextMenuPicture` is the context menu for right click on a picture.

And so on..

[ContextMenus Add-In for Office 2010](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/contextmenusaddin) Use this add-in to help determine the context menu names. After install the context menu name appears on the bottom of the menu.

Also make sure in the ThisAddIn.cs file, you have overridden the following method

```
protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new Ribbon1();
}
```

Comment: thanks, that add-in helped me - in my case it was ContextMenuInlinePicture - but now I have problem how to access currently selected inline pictere by IRibbonControl reference from attached event. Selection on AttachmentSelection did not worked.