# can we have a context menu on in mail attachements i.e attachments inside a mail

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

can we have a context menu on in mail **attachments** i.e attachments inside a mail . How can i use my context menu for in mail attachments mostly of type rich text

Comment: The answer is over here ... [Add attachment context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847152/add-attachment-context-menu-outlook-2013). Please, perform minimum research before posting the question.

Comment: mail attachment for rich type type of mail not for attachements that are attached

Comment: As I said, do more research on your own, all the answers already available. [Outlook 2010 Context Menu For Embedded Attachments - idMso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307143/outlook-2010-context-menu-for-embedded-attachments-idmso) . The list of available idMso is over here [Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798); you would need to look at "wordcontrols" as the editor is Word and context menu you are trying to extend will be there.